# is functions folder (firebase functions) on angular project is visible to client

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a folder named "functions" on my angular project that was created by "firebase init functions" command

I use this folder to deploy functions to the cloud
I would like to know if their code is exposed to the end client through the firebase hosting?

Comment: The role of Firebase Hosting is only to send your Angular files up to the client when they are needed (i.e. requested by the client).For more information check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620717/angulars-services-processed-on-client-side-or-server-side)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya thank you for your answer. My question is : i s it safe to to deploy those functions to firebase hosting from "functions" folder at the angular project while not risking it by expose it to the client ?

Comment: you can customize which folder is deployed to the site by [firebase.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites)